# Extract multiple JSON objects from txt file

Tags: json, jq

I am a arch linux user and i meet issue with JSON jq generation.

My aim is to run pacman -Qi in order to list all packages and dependancies and convert it into JSON.

However i just want the Name, Version, Description and URL fields.

I've tried to export the output of pacman -Qi with greps patterns with the following command :

```
pacman -Qi | grep "Name\|Version\|Description\|URL" > /home/packages.txt
```

After i try to generate a JSON file with jq with the following command :

```
jq -R -n -c '[inputs|split(",")|{(.[0]):.[1]}] | add' packages.txt > packages-raw.json
```

After that i have a JSON output not formatted but it seems to be a JSON output.

I format the file with

```
jq . packages-raw.json
```

The JSON seems to be formatted but when I run with VScode, there is only one object.

Could you help me about the formatting ?

Thank you by advance,

Best regards

I would like an output as :

```
{
  "Name"            : "acl",
  "Version"         : "2.2.53-1",
  "Description"     : "Access control list utilities": " libraries and headers",
  "URL"             : "http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/acl"
}

{ "Name"            : "archlinux-keyring",
  "Version"         : "20190827-1",
  "Description"     : "Arch Linux PGP keyring",
  "URL"             : "https://projects.archlinux.org/archlinux-keyring.git/"
}
```

For the moment i have an output as :

```
{ "Name : acl": null, "Version : 2.2.53-1": null, "Description : Access control list utilities": " libraries and headers", "URL : http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/acl": null, "Name : archlinux-keyring": null, "Version : 20190827-1": null, "Description : Arch Linux PGP keyring": null, "URL : https://projects.archlinux.org/archlinux-keyring.git/": null, "Name : argon2": null, "Version : 20190702-1": null, "Description : A password-hashing function (reference C implementation)": null, "URL : https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2": null,
```

Comment: Please format your post first to understand the exact thing that you want

Comment: The "output" shown at the very end of the question is not valid JSON, and so cannot be the output of any jq command.  Please fix it, and clarify whether you are showing packages-raw.json.  You do not need to provide the entire output of `pacman -Qi` but it might be helpful if you showed a representative sample.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Arch system but from looking at

- https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/22575
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327810/get-info-about-installed-and-remote-packages-with-pacman/327811

I assume the output of `pacman -Qi` looks like the following

```
Name            : vi
Version         : 1:070224-2
Description     : The original ex/vi text editor
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/
Licenses        : custom:ex
Groups          : base
Provides        : None
Depends On      : ncurses
Optional Deps   : s-nail: used by the preserve command for notification [installed]
Required By     : None
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 290.00 KiB
Packager        : Evangelos Foutras <evangelos@foutrelis.com>
Build Date      : Sun 06 Sep 2015 09:34:15 PM CEST
Install Date    : Mon 03 Oct 2016 07:18:13 PM CEST
Install Reason  : Explicitly installed
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature

Name            : dbus
Version         : 1.4.1-1
URL             : http://www.freedesktop.org/Software/dbus
Licenses        : GPL custom
Groups          : None
Provides        : None
Depends On      : dbus-core>=1.4.1 libx11
Optional Deps   : None
Required By     : avahi perl-net-dbus qt system-tools-backends
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 112.00 K
Packager        : Jan de Groot <jgc@archlinux.org>
Architecture    : i686
Build Date      : Wed Dec 22 14:39:28 2010
Install Date    : Sun Jan 2 16:05:50 2011
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
Install Script  : No
Description     : Freedesktop.org message bus system
```

Here is a jq script that converts such values into a stream of key-value objects
and collects them into aggregate objects based on the value of the Name attribute

```
def kvpairs:                                                    # e.g. (note spaces)
    inputs                                                      # "Name    : vi"
  | capture("^(?<key>[^:]+):(?<value>.+)$")                     # { "key": "Name   ", "value": " vi" }
  | (.key, .value) |= gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$";"")                    # { "key": "Name", "value": "vi" }
  ;

  reduce kvpairs as $kv (
      { result:{}, cur:null }                                   # initial state
    ; if $kv.key == "Name" then .cur = $kv.value else . end     # track current object
    | .result[.cur][$kv.key] = $kv.value                        # apply update to current object
  )
| .result[]                                                     # generate result
| { Name, Version, Description, URL }                           # with only these members
```

Sample execution assuming the above in `test.jq` and pacman output in `test.pac`

```
$ jq -MRn -f test.jq test.pac
{
  "Name": "vi",
  "Version": "1:070224-2",
  "Description": "The original ex/vi text editor",
  "URL": "http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/"
}
{
  "Name": "dbus",
  "Version": "1.4.1-1",
  "Description": "Freedesktop.org message bus system",
  "URL": "http://www.freedesktop.org/Software/dbus"
}
```